# Creating a messages list in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a messages list, like Facebook.

1. Showing only last the message from a users conversation (history)
2. when I send show mine , when I get answer show answered messages (1 row)

**database data** :

[image]

**SQL query**

```sql
SELECT m.message_id, u.username, m.subject, m.message
     , m.status, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.date) as date
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN messages m ON m.sender_id = u.id
 WHERE m.message_id in (SELECT max(msg.message_id) 
                          FROM messages msg 
                         WHERE msg.receiver_id = 3 
                         GROUP BY sender_id)
 UNION
SELECT m.message_id, u.username, m.subject, m.message
     , m.status, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.date) as date
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN messages m ON m.receiver_id = u.id
 WHERE m.message_id in (SELECT max(msg.message_id)  
                          FROM messages msg 
                         WHERE msg.sender_id = 3 
                         GROUP BY receiver_id)
 GROUP BY u.username
 ORDER BY date DESC
```

I try to receive all messages which I send (my id = 3) and all those sent to me and group by username

**SQL result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [message_id] => 10
            [username] => 8888
            [subject] => без темы
            [message] => 555
            [status] => 0
            [date] => 11 August 2012, 2:22
            [user_image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/65_empty.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [message_id] => 7
            [username] => 8888
            [subject] => hi
            [message] => 333
            [status] => 0
            [date] => 11 August 2012, 2:15
            [user_image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/65_empty.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [message_id] => 4
            [username] => 6666
            [subject] => РўРµРјР°
            [message] => 2
            [status] => 0
            [date] => 11 August 2012, 2:02
            [user_image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/65_empty.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [message_id] => 1
            [username] => fffffffff
            [subject] => privet
            [message] => tttt
            [status] => 0
            [date] => 11 August 2012, 1:38
            [user_image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/65_empty.jpg
        )

)
```

As you can see `GROUP BY` username do not work. It shows 3->7 and 7->3 but 7->3 was an answer and last message. I do not know why group does not work. Maybe you can help me with more easier way to solve this problem?

So, the SQL must have "sender_id = 3" , "receiver_id = 3" and from my table data result must be

- message_id -> 1
- message_id -> 4
- message_id -> 10

Comment: If you have an SQL question, you can prepare a modifiable test case at the awesome http://sqlfiddle.com/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query is producing the “right” results, as if you'd like to see the last message in some of the conversations, you should really group by the `conversation_id`. I don't see this field you in schema though.

If you do `WHERE sender_id = 3 GROUP BY receiver_id`, then it is correct, that query returns you messages 1 and 7, 'cos those messages had been sent to *different* people, thus in your design they're different conversations.

If you want to see only the very last message sent by you in general, just remove `GROUP BY` in the second part of your `UNION`. Otherwise, consider re-designing your schema.

---

**EDIT:**

Try this query:

```
SELECT m.message_id, u.username, m.subject, m.message,
       m.status, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.date) as `date`
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN messages m ON m.sender_id = u.id
 WHERE m.message_id IN (
    SELECT max(message_id) 
      FROM messages
     WHERE receiver_id = 3 OR sender_id = 3
     GROUP BY least(sender_id,receiver_id), 
              greatest(sender_id,receiver_id)
    );
```

Some notes:

1. `UNION` is not needed anymore;
2. This approach will treat all e-mails between 2 parties as a single conversation, which is not always true. You might want to re-design this approach;
3. It is a bad style to use reserved words (like `date`) for columns' names or aliases, try to avoid this. Or use backticks if you do use them.

Comment: I want one user one conversation so here still will be a problem if user with id (1) writes to (3) conversation_id will be 3 ... and if 3->1 then id = 1 showning the list I get the same 3->1 and 1->3 not the last message